# How to calculate 2 columns values with ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I would like to calculate 2 columns values with ecto like following SQL

```
SELECT goal, assist, (goal + assist) as point
FROM game
```

I would like to add point column with goal + assist columns.
Please give me an advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Ecto.Query.API.fragment/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html?#fragment/1).

```rb
from g in Game,
  select: %{
    goal: g.goal,
    assist: g.assist,
    point: fragment("? + ?", g.goal, g.assist)
  }
```

Comment: I cannot check it right now but wouldn’t just `g.goal + g.assist` work in the `select` as well?

Comment: @Hauleth they might, indeed, I cannot check now either; `fragment/1` is kinda more generic, so I would stick to it without wild-guessing in each particular case. Also, I have a wild guess that `fragment/1` would issue a more understandable error when the input is inconsistent (e. g. `NULL`.)